# Snap in "snap your fingers"

Tags: word-in-context, word-meaning

What definition of the word **snap** is used in the phrase **"snap your fingers"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OED:

> **snap, v.**
>   **12. b.** To cause (the fingers) to make a sharp noise by striking against the ball of the thumb, esp. as a sign of delight or contempt. Also *fig.*
>
> > ***1839*** T. Mitchell Frogs of Aristoph. 66 note, "At its conclusion he snaps his fingers in sovereign contempt."

Comment: This is a video of someone _snapping thier fingers_: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MqjXoQdl9g

Comment: The definition has forgotten the abracadabra element, and the use of the snap to represent a time span less than the blink of an eye.